# Python one-liner to robustly extract result of a regular expression search

Tags: python, regex, lambda

Is it possible to express the following with the help of a simpler one-line expression?

```
def search(x):
   # Return a keyword or None if not found.
   ret = re.search('^(foo|bar|baz)', x)
   return ret.group() if ret else None

texts = ['fool', 'minibar', 'bark', 'honk']
map(search, texts)
```

This returns: `['foo', None, 'bar', None]`

Searching a text in a string and retrieving the matching token is a pretty common task and I wondered whether there is a more direct way to achieve the same.

I would like to write this using a one-liner, without having to declare a separate function. Do `re` or other modules offer a more direct way to find and retrieve matches, basically a short-cut for my above function? For instance, does something like the following exist?

```
texts = ['fool', 'minibar', 'honk']
map(lambda x: re.search_and_retrieve, texts)
```

Or is there a neat, readable way to test and safely retrieve the output from `re.search()` in one line?

Comment: Readability trumps one-liners (almost) all the time. My advise: Don't bother

Comment: @MSeifert I fully agree. I just wonder if there was a simple way to achieve this with module `re`. If there was not, I'm very happy to read that answer. In that sense, I don't consider this an 'opinion-based' question. I simply don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but you don't want this:

```
(lambda txt: (lambda x: x.group() if x else None)(re.search('foo', txt)))
```

Sorry, `None` is not a `Maybe` or `Option`, you can't succinctly chain a function to the value if it exists. (If you miss these guys, look at Coconut language which extends Python.)

Comment: This indeed looks ugly but answers my question. Thanks. I rather hoped to find a special function like `re.search_value(pattern, text)` that returns `None` or the matched value(s) instead of an optional object of type `_sre.SRE_Match` as `re.search()` does.

Comment: If lambdas allowed local binding (`x = foo() in x + x`) it could be easier, but without that, the only remaining option is inlining. Also, lambda syntax is a bit verbose in Python (compared to e.g. ES6).

Answer (score 3):

This is obviously hacky, but for the sake of completeness, here is an alternative to the existing answers which does not require consecutive nested lambdas or multiple calls to the regex engine:

```
>>> map(lambda x: getattr(re.search('^(foo|bar|baz)', x), "group", lambda: None)(), texts)
['foo', None, 'bar', None]
```

`getattr(expression, method_name, lambda: None)()` is approximately equivalent to `expression.method_name() if expression else None` except you don't have to write `expression` twice. I don't consider it good practice -- identifiers should be identifiers, not string literals -- but it's an interesting concept to play around with in non-production-quality code.

Comment: Another answer to creatively circumvent the problem of retrieving an optional result. Many thanks for the idea, although I'd stick with the alternative to write a separate function for this.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension would look like this:

```
[re.findall('^(foo|bar|baz)', i)[0] if re.search('^(foo|bar|baz)', i) else None for i in texts]
```

Comment: But `i` will be the complete string, not the captured group. He wants "foo", not "fool".

Comment: Why not `re.search(...).group()` instead of `re.findall(...)[0]`?

Comment: All right, output looks better now :-) The advantage this has over 9000's answer is that it doesn't require nested lambdas, which some may consider a hindrance to readability. The disadvantage is that it performs the regex twice, which makes it about half as efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter`:

```
texts = ['fool', 'minibar', 'honk']
final_val = list(filter(lambda x:x is not None, map(lambda x: re.search('^(foo|bar|baz)', x).group(0) if re.search('^(foo|bar|baz)', x) is not None else None, texts)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The lambda function look like this:(This helps you yo solve the problem)

```
texts = ['fool', 'minibar', 'bark', 'honk']

map(lambda x : re.search('^(foo|bar|baz)', x).group() if re.search('^(foo|bar|baz)', x) else None, texts)
```

Comment: True, this is a one-liner, and it solves my problem. But it computes the result twice, which for me is a bad feature.